# Google Cloud Platform, ML Engine, "No module named absl"

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, object-detection, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to train an object detector using TensorFlow following the following tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine

The tutorial asks to use `object_detection.train`, however this has been moved to legacy so I've used `object_detection.model_main` instead. Line 21 of this python file calls the module `absl`, however this causes the following error (from the GCP Logs Viewer).

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 162, in _run_module_as_main "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in
>   run_globals File
>   "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_main.py",
>   line 21, in  from absl import flags ImportError: No module
>   named absl

I tried to include `absl>=0.1` in the required packages section of the `setup.py` file for the object_detection package but that didn't work. Next I tried to move my absl folder into the `models/research/object_detection` directory before packaging and starting the job, but that didn't work either. How do I fix this? I'm very new to Tensorflow and the GCP platform so your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to access `flags` through `tf.app.flags` without the absl package. If you replace each occurrence of `flags` (lowercase) with `tf.app.flags`, remove the absl import, and remove the lines containing `flags.mark_flag_as_required`, will the application work?

Comment: @MatthewScarpino Having to replace every single mention of a module in every single file is incredibly tedious. Code that actually works with the modules it claims to need is really ideal.

Comment: @Tejas I have managed to overcome the error. The package that you should be adding to `REQUIRED_PACKAGES` list in setup.py is `'absl-py>=0.1.0'`. Apart from that, download [this package](https://pypi.org/project/absl-py/#files) tar.gz file to `models/research/dist` . Install by running `pip install absl-py` . Then, when starting the job add `dist/avsl-0.4.0.tar.gz` to the variables passed to the `--packages` flag.

Comment: @PhilippSh your solution works perfect. Why not add it to the answers?

Answer (score 2):

The package that you should be adding to `REQUIRED_PACKAGES` list in setup.py is `'absl-py>=0.1.0'`. Apart from that, download this package tar.gz file to `models/research/dist` . Install by running `pip install absl-py` . Then, when starting the job add `dist/avsl-0.4.0.tar.gz` to the variables passed to the `--packages` flag.